# SQL Calendar and me

Tags: sql, sql-server

If we have a data in a table something like this:

```
YEAR    MONTH   customer_group  Gross_sale
------------------------------------------
2014    10      c               36500
```

Is it possible to get data something like this, having week column based on month and days based on week, for the entire year?

```
YEAR    MONTH   Week    Day Customer_GROUP  Gross_sale
------------------------------------------------------
2014    10      1       1   C               36500
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Don't store year/month/day etc in separate columns. Have one date column instead.

Comment: Also, which dbms are you using? (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: I think it would be better to get the date from the db, then calculate the the week number in the programming language (php for example) side .

Comment: @jarlh: i have one column as date, but user requested to see data on year, month week and day. i am using sql server 2008r2

Comment: any suggestion techie...... appreciate your help.

Comment: Show us your current SELECT, the one with different year, month etc result, and maybe we can adjust it.